# Implementing access control in django based on role

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I need help in implementing access control on my django project. There are 2 main roles , sales and developer. In these 2 roles , there is another hierarchy , manager and non-manager. Based on their roles , I would want to display different things and do different types of queries.

The method I am using currently using is to extend my user model to include these roles , and using if statements within my template to display the functionalities accordingly.

Here is my model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    role = (
        ('sm','sales_manager'),
        ('s','sales'),
        ('rm','rnd_manager'),
        ('r','rnd')
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_type = models.TextField(max_length=500, choices= role)
    contact = models.IntegerField(default=92388112)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

Here is my view:

```
    @login_required(login_url='login')
def rnd/home(request):
    print(request.user.username)
    context = {
    'userProfile' : UserProfile.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'rnd/home.html',context)
```

here is a relevant part of my template:

```
  {%if user.get_UserProfile.user_type == 's' or user.get_UserProfile.user_type == 'sm' %}
            <p>Sales</p>
            {%else%}
            <p>RnD</p>
            {%endif%}
            <li>
```

However , my for loop does not work. It does not throw any error , but does nothing as well.  When I'm logged in as a 'r' type , sales still gets shown on my screen.

It would be great if someone could answer me as well as leave some tips on the best way to implement such access control, not only in features but also in filtering the data shown in common features.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any **for loop** in your code. But if you just want **UserProfile** from **User**, you can get a **OneToOne** model directly from either way. In your case, it would be `user.userProfile.user_type`.

You might also want to look at [Django Custom Permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions)